# java program for division of one number of any range by another

Tags: java, math

Write a program in java to divide one number by another. But these number can have any number of digits(means the numbers may be of 100,200 or more than these digits.)

Comment: No, I will not (do your homework).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your question is too vague and sounds like homework.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service... Code comes with good will from the OP. A hint, however: have a look at `BigInteger`.

Comment: You didn't even bother to add "how do I"

Comment: It is an interview question and I wanna the answer.

Comment: yet you didn't formulate this as a question, but rather as a homework dump

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Usually when one asks a question on here, you need show a little more effort.

Comment: @w4rumy when we disregard the fact that it looks like a _very_ lazy question, and that it asks for more than one thing, and that it's a bit lacking in english (not a reason to downvote), "how do I divide two numbers of unlimited length in Java? I know I could implement long division, but there must be a better way" is a decent question.

Comment: Is it not inappropriate on SO to be providing solutions that the OP is admittedly using to cheat on an exam?

Answer (score 4):

If a number can be of virtually any length, use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).  `BigInteger` provides a `divide` method.

Here's an example:

```
BigInteger a = new BigInteger("7583584848488756569");
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("-357457473437373");

BigInteger x = a.divide(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `java.math.BigInteger.divide(BigInteger val)` returns a `BigInteger` whose value is (this / val).

Using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger bi1, bi2, bi3;

        bi1 = new BigInteger("-100");
        bi2 = new BigInteger("3");

        // divide bi1 with bi2
    bi3 = bi1.divide(bi2); 

        String str = "Division result is " +bi3;

    // print bi3 value
    System.out.println( str );
```

The output will be

```
Division result is -33
```

Answer (score 0):

A facetious answer:

For a numeric value 'x' and a numeric value 'y' there is a special operator `/` that when placed between these two values evaluates to a number representing the number of times the second can "fit" into the first i.e.

```
int x = 200;
int y = 100;
System.out.println(x / y);
```

will return

```
2
```

Comment: "the numbers may be of 100,200 or more digits"

Comment: @JanDvorak "A facetious answer"

Comment: Facetious - adj. Treating serious issues with deliberately inappropriate humor; flippant